# is IMAP NOTIFY command supported by Gmail or yahoo?

Tags: imap, gmail-imap

Hi i am implementing IMAP mail client. does gmail or yahoo mail server does support IMAP NOTIFY command or how to check a particular mail server does support IMAP NOTIFY command.

I tried to get capabilities.

Capabilities for Gmail/Yahoo

Gmail :

CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN

Yahoo :

[CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 ID NAMESPACE X-ID-ACLID UIDPLUS LITERAL+ CHILDREN XAPPLEPUSHSERVICE XYMHIGHESTMODSEQ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=XYMCOOKIE AUTH=XYMECOOKIE AUTH=XYMCOOKIEB64 AUTH=XYMPKI]

one more question is i could not able to able to see **IDLE** in yahoo CAPABILITIES. its mean yahoo does not support IDLE? and i could not able to **NOTIFY** command from both. pls help me out....

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to check is to list the capabilities, so your conclusions are correct: Gmail supports IDLE only, yahoo supports neither NOTIFY nor IDLE.

Comment: ya fine, and gmail not supporting NOTIFY also right?

Comment: Gmail does not support NOTIFY.